# array_length() of an empty array returning NULL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm developing some stored proceduces in PL/pgSQL and some of them are giving me some problems. The sprocs I'm developing receive by parameter an array which I use in a FOR LOOP to get all its elements. To define the upper bound of the FOR LOOP I use the array_length function.

```
FOR i IN 1..array_length(array,1) LOOP

   --array[i] something in here

END LOOP;
```

The problems occurs when I give to the sprocs an empty array. Instead of not entering the cycle, the sproc simply returns an error, stating that the upper bound of the FOR LOOP is NULL. Shouldn’t it be **0**?

Am I doing anything wrong with the FOR LOOP?

Is there any other way to use the same bounds in a LOOP without it returning NULL when using an empty array?

**Note**: I know I can always use a condition before the LOOP, like this:

```
IF array_length(array,1) IS NOT NULL THEN
```

but the problem is: This sproc is supposed to process thousands of calls in the shortest amount of time. As so, I'm not looking to something that adds an unnecessary overhead to the processing. I'm just looking if there is any way to “cycle” an empty array in a LOOP.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As always, if you want to have different behavior for NULL values, use the `coalesce` construct:

```
FOR i IN 1..coalesce(array_length(array, 1), 0) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', array[i];
END LOOP;
```

As for the return value: `array_length(x, N)` returns the number of elements in **Nth** dimension. Since an empty array has no dimensions, it returns NULL. You're right that it's counterintuitive if you only consider simple arrays, but makes sense for multi-dimensional arrays.

**Edit:** Like Erwin Brandstetter wrote in the comments, it's more correct to use array_lower/upper to loop over array indices. These will work for arrays that are not 1-based. These also take a dimension argument and require coalesce:

```
FOR i IN coalesce(array_lower(array, 1), 1)..coalesce(array_upper(array, 1), 1) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', array[i];
END LOOP;
```

Comment: This form is still not 100 % safe since Postgres supports [arbitrary array subscripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1). You would have to use `array_lower()` and `array_upper()` to be sure.

Comment: for the upper bound, shouldn't be coalesce(array_upper(array, 1), 0) ?
 As 1 .. 1 will still make it to enter the loop once.

Answer (score 4):

#### To note: `'{}'::int[] IS DISTINCT FROM null`

**`'{}'`** is an "empty array". An empty array is **not** the same as **`null`**. But an empty array has unset internal boundaries, hence you get `null` for any of these auxiliary functions:

```sql
SELECT array_length('{}'::int[], 1)  -- null
     , array_upper('{}'::int[], 1)   -- null
     , array_lower('{}'::int[], 1);  -- null
```

And that's what this question is about.

#### Solution for empty arrays

To avoid the problem with **empty arrays** altogether, loop through the array with [**`FOREACH`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY), introduced with Postgres **9.1**:

```
FOREACH i IN ARRAY $1
LOOP
   -- do something
END LOOP;
```

#### Solution for empty arrays *and* `null`

If **`null`** input is also possible, you need to do more. For example, if `null` shall be treated like an empty array ( = do not enter the loop at all), throw in `COALESCE`:

```
FOREACH i IN ARRAY COALESCE($1, '{}')
LOOP
   -- do something
END LOOP;
```

Related:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

#### Pure SQL is often better

You might be able to avoid looping altogether and use plain SQL with [**`unnest()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) instead. Set-based operations are typically faster than looping in PostgreSQL.

Example:

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT elem || 'foo'
FROM   unnest($1) AS t(elem);
```

See:

- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)

Comment: That doesn't help: `ERROR:  FOREACH expression must not be null`. And I cannot use the dollar sign.

Comment: @Jarekczek: This question is about *empty arrays*. Not the same as `null` input. Consider added clarifications above. If you cannot use the dollar sign, use [named function parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) instead. Typically preferable in modern PL/pgSQL anyway. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26793207/939860