# PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL random value from array of values

Tags: arrays, postgresql, random, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

How can I declare an array like variable with two or three values and get them randomly during execution?

```
a := [1, 2, 5] -- sample sake
select random(a) -- returns random value
```

Any suggestion where to start?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_pick()
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ('[0:2]={1,2,5}'::int[])[trunc(random() * 3)::int];
$func$;
```

`random()` returns a value `x` where `0.0 <= x < 1.0`. Multiply by `3` and truncate it with `trunc()` (slightly faster than `floor()`) to get `0`, `1`, or `2` with *exactly equal chance*.

Postgres indexes are 1-based by default (as per SQL standard). This would be off-by-1. We could increment by 1 every time - or declare the array index to start with `0` instead. Slightly faster, yet. See:

- [Normalize array subscripts so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-so-they-start-with-1)
- [The manual on mathematical functions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)

`PARALLEL SAFE` for Postgres 9.6 or later. See:

- [PARALLEL label for a function with SELECT and INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990941/parallel-label-for-a-function-with-select-and-insert/70991141#70991141)
- [When to mark functions as PARALLEL RESTRICTED vs PARALLEL SAFE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/251274/3684)

You can use the plain `SELECT` statement if you don't want to create a function:

```
SELECT ('[0:2]={1,2,5}'::int[])[trunc(random() * 3)::int];
```

Answer (score 68):

Try this one:

```
select (array['Yes', 'No', 'Maybe'])[floor(random() * 3 + 1)];
```

Comment: Would this work the same in case there is more than 3 items in the array? Also would you please know how to get 2 random items rather than 1? Thanks!

Comment: It would be good to clarify what the magic numbers represent. If I wanted to try this on an array with a different number of items, what magic numbers would I use? I'd imagine the `3` here represents the length of the array, then regardless of the array length we should always `+ 1`?

Comment: Yes, the '3' should be the number of elements in the array. The '1' is for making the indexing 1-based so it shouldn't be changed.

Comment: this is a great solution. thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to do the same thing

```
WITH arr AS (
    SELECT '{1, 2, 5}'::INT[] a
)
SELECT a[1 + floor((random() * array_length(a, 1)))::int] FROM arr;
```

You can change the array to any type you would like.

Comment: this is the simplest answer of all and does not use a fixed value for the index, instead it uses the array length.. for my humble point of view it might be the most correct answer! Thanks for sharing! :D

Answer (score 8):

[Erwin Brandstetter answered the OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328164/1801588) well enough. However, for others looking for understanding how to randomly pick elements from more complex arrays (like me some two months ago), I expanded his function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_pick( a anyarray, OUT x anyelement )
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
  IF a = '{}' THEN
    x := NULL::TEXT;
  ELSE
    WHILE x IS NULL LOOP
      x := a[floor(array_lower(a, 1) + (random()*( array_upper(a, 1) -  array_lower(a, 1)+1) ) )::int];
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Few assumptions:

- this is not only for integer arrays, but for arrays of any type
- we ignore NULL data; NULL is returned only if the array is empty or if NULL is inserted (values of other non-array types produce an error)
- the array don't need to be formatted as usual - the array index may start and end anywhere, may have gaps etc.
- this is for one-dimensional arrays

Other notes:

- without the first `IF` statement, empty array would lead to an endless loop
- without the loop, gaps and NULLs would make the function return NULL
- omit both `array_lower` calls if you know that your arrays start at zero
- with gaps in the index, you will need `array_upper` instead of `array_length`; without gaps, it's the same (not sure which is faster, but they shouldn't be much different)
- the `+1` after second `array_lower` serves to get the last value in the array with the same probability as any other; otherwise it would need the `random()`'s output to be exactly 1, which never happens
- this is considerably slower than Erwin's solution, and likely to be an overkill for the your needs; in practice, most people would mix an ideal cocktail from the two

Comment: Why not use `array_length`?

Comment: This causes an infinite loop on arrays that contain only `NULL` values. Might want to do something like `a := ARRAY(SELECT x FROM unnest(a) AS rel(x) WHERE x NOT NULL)`.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pick_random( members anyarray )
RETURNS anyelement AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN members[trunc(random() * array_length(members, 1) + 1)];
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

or

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pick_random( members anyarray )
RETURNS anyelement AS
$$
  SELECT (array_agg(m1 order by random()))[1]
  FROM unnest(members) m1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```

For bigger datasets, see:

- http://blog.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/2009/03/08/selecting-random-rows-from-a-table/
- http://www.depesz.com/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/
- https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-and-other-methods-for-getting-random-tuples/
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html

Comment: I definitely like this one as it uses the array as an argument and then array_length instead of the hard-coded number. I recently became a fan of `width_bucket`, so my version has `RETURN vals[width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, array_length(vals, 1))];` but otherwise it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION random_pick(p_items anyarray)
RETURNS anyelement AS
$$
   SELECT unnest(p_items) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: This no longer seems to work in PostgreSQL 9.6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179012/how-to-shuffle-array-in-postgresql-9-6-and-also-lower-versions