# Syntax error in plpgsql function with if statement and variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to SQL and don't think I understand how to write if else statements. The following code block produces a syntax error at the if statement.

```
create or replace function weight_from_days_ago (days_ago int, difficulty int, user_level int, root_score int)
returns int as $$
begin
    declare average_days_ago int := (select avg(days_ago));
    if average_days_ago = 0 then 
    average_days_ago := 1;
    return ((select coalesce(days_ago, 0))/average_days_ago) + abs(difficulty - user_level) + root_score);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This function, without the additional variable, also produces a syntax error when run.

```
begin
    return (select coalesce(days_ago, 0)/(if ((select avg(days_ago)) = 0) then 1 else (select avg(days_ago))) + abs(difficulty - user_level) + root_score);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error isn't that difficult to fix, just follow error messages database engine reports; it's about superfluous closing bracket, missing `end if`. Moreover, if `if` condition isn't satisfied, function ends without returning any value (which is invalid) so you have to fix it. How? `ELSE` might be an obvious choice.

Furthermore, what is the purpose of selecting average value of a scalar `in` parameter? What is average of 13? It is 13, of course ... so, why *averaging* it at all?

Anyway: such a code compiles and returns result (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Npn7bRZ1):

```
create or replace function weight_from_days_ago (days_ago int, difficulty int, user_level int, root_score int)
returns int as $$
  declare average_days_ago int := avg(days_ago);
begin  
    if average_days_ago = 0 then 
      average_days_ago := 1;
      return ((select coalesce(days_ago, 0))/average_days_ago) + abs(difficulty - user_level) + root_score;
    else
      return null;
    end if;
end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

However, I'd suggest you to think it over and fix logical issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are obvious syntax errors and nonsense like [Littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot) already pointed out. Read the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS).

Moreover, there is nothing in your function that would require a procedural language like PL/pgSQL to begin with. An expression is evaluated. Just use a plain SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weight_from_days_ago (days_ago int, difficulty int, user_level int, root_score int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT COALESCE(days_ago, 0) / GREATEST(days_ago, 1)
     + abs(difficulty - user_level)
     + root_score;
$func$;
```

See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Also, there is no `IF` in SQL (only `CASE`). That makes your 2nd attempt invalid. Don't confuse SQL syntax with PL/pgSQL syntax. I use [`GREATEST()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) instead (which would also catch negative integers).

You can also use a "standard SQL function" in **Postgres 14** or newer:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weight_from_days_ago (days_ago int, difficulty int, user_level int, root_score int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN COALESCE(days_ago, 0) / GREATEST(days_ago, 1)
     + abs(difficulty - user_level)
     + root_score;
```

Even a bit shorter and faster, yet. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

See also:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)
- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455177/function-executes-faster-without-strict-modifier/65672967#65672967)
- [PARALLEL label for a function with SELECT and INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990941/parallel-label-for-a-function-with-select-and-insert/70991141#70991141)

Aside: `abs(difficulty - user_level)` looks counter-intuitive, too. Lower levels get the same bonus as higher levels?