# Array search does not use index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have a Postgres 9.2 server with the following table:

Table `A` with a single column `code` and a B-tree index on it:

```
db=> \d A
Table "public.A"
Column  |  Type  | Modifiers 
--------+--------+-----------
 code   | bigint | not null

 Indexes:
 "A_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (code)
```

I have a simple PLPGSQL function as follows, simplified for ease of following:

```
create or replace function list (bigint)
   RETURNS bigint[] AS '
    DECLARE
            arr        bigint[];
            c          ALIAS FOR $1;
    begin
            arr[0] = c * 1;
            arr[1] = c * 2;
            ...
            ...
            arr[10] = c * 1024;
            return arr;
END;
' language plpgsql;
```

I notice that the index is not used if invoke the function:

```
db => explain select * from A where code = ANY(list(3234234234));
                           QUERY PLAN                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on A (cost=0.00..1440291398.32 rows=10 width=219)
Filter: (code = ANY (list(3234234234::bigint)))
```

No luck even if I typecast the output of the function to be `ANY(list(3234234234) :: bigint[])`

Of course, if I manually create a list it works perfectly.

```
db=> explain select * from A where code = ANY( '{21312,13123,1312312,1231312,123213231}' :: bigint[]); 
                                   QUERY PLAN                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bitmap Heap Scan on A  (cost=538.09..558.17 rows=5 width=219)
Recheck Cond: (code = ANY ('{21312,13123,1312312,1231312,123213231}'::bigint[]))
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on A_pkey  (cost=0.00..538.09 rows=5 width=0)
        Index Cond: (code = ANY ('{21312,13123,1312312,1231312,123213231}'::bigint[]))
```

Why does Postgres do a sequential scan when using the function?
How do I get it to do index scan with the function?

Comment: Do you actually need a non-standard 0-based array index or is a default index starting with 1 just as well?

Comment: The solution is to rewrite it as suggested by @ErwinBrandstetter. Rewrite it as an immutable function. The query starts using the index.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  It was a typo to use an index that started at [1]. Thanks for writing such a nice post that I learned so much from!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why is the index not used?

The function returns 11 bigint numbers, but Postgres does not really know that, since the PL/pgSQL function is a **black box** for the query planner, and it's `VOLATILE`, too. That tells Postgres to expect a different array for ever call. Postgres reckons it'll be cheaper to hit the table directly with a possibly big number of elements in the array. The expectation is different for the alternative with a fixed number of just 5 elements.

#### Improved function

Use this simple, `IMMUTABLE` SQL function instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function list (c bigint)
  RETURNS bigint[] LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT array_agg($1 * (2^g)::int) FROM generate_series(0, 10) g';
```

Simpler and faster in several ways, and much rather allows index usage.

- Lots of assignments are comparatively expensive in PL/pgSQL, even more so for assembling long arrays, since the whole array has to be rewritten with every assignment. BTW, the correct assignment operator in PL/pgSQL is **`:=`** not `=`:

  - [The forgotten assignment operator "=" and the commonplace ":="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace)
- Default function volatility is `VOLATILE`. Your function can be `IMMUTABLE`: the same output for the same input is guaranteed at all times. Can help to optimize repeated calls.
- You whole syntax was outdated and you don't need PL/pgSQL at all. Simple SQL functions can be inlined in the context of outer queries.
- Finally, PL/pgSQL is not always a good choice for functions that are nested in the context of bigger queries. They are black boxes for the query planner and act as optimization barriers. Details:

  - [PostgreSQL Stored Procedure Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)
  - [How to get query runtime in PL/pgSQL to be as fast as console query runtime?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58365/3684)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/60019/1)

Postgres arrays index starts with 1 by default. If you actually need your arrays to start with **index 0**, you could use the technique from this related answer to shift it (but I don't expect you need it):

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1/12012285#12012285so-they-start-with-1)

Comment: Thanks a lot but this is not due to the size of the list returned by the function. Even when I reduced the function to return a list with just 2 elements, it still performs a sequential scan. Looking fwd to looking at your improved function though.

Comment: Also, the function returns just 10 elements not 1024 as you mention in your response.

Comment: @user3000172: Ah, I see now: `arr[10]`. Sorry, overlooked that bit. Updated my answer. The gist of it remains the same.

Comment: That worked out. When I rewrite the function using the IMMUTABLE clause it worked out. Thank you much!

Comment: Also note the updated fiddle now. And on the topic of array elements: 0 .. 10 - that's 11 elements. ;) Ah, and did you test with an IMMUTABLE PLPGSQL function or my SQL variant?