# Select every first element of array of integer arrays to array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

How to select every first element of array of integer arrays to array?
`{{1,2,3},{2,15,32},{5,16,14},...}` -> `{1,2,5,...}`

Comment: Some more information about your context would be appropriate. Postgres version? Table definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL will allow asking for a slice outside of the array size, and assuming there will never be more than 999 subarrays, we can use this monstrosity

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT array[array[1,2,3], array[2,15,32], array[5,16,14]] as arr)
SELECT array_agg(arr)
  FROM (SELECT unnest(arr[1:999][1]) as arr from data) data2;
```

You can of course make the constant 999 larger if needed, it is just a random large number I threw in there.

The reason why this is so complicated is that if you would use just `arr[1:999][1]` you would still get a two-dimensional array, but with only the first elements. In this case `{{1}, {2}, {5}}`. If we use `unnest()` we can make it into a set, which can then be fed into `array_agg()` via subselect.

It would be nice to use `array_agg(unnest(arr[1:999][1]))` but the aggregation function doesn't like sets and I don't know if there is a way to convert it on the fly.

You can also use the actual array length, but it might cause unnecessary computation

```
SELECT unnest(arr[1:array_length(arr, 1)][1]) as arr from data
```

**Note**

If the arrays could be unnested by one level, you could just index the arrays and then use `array_agg()` to convert it back into an array with a lot simpler syntax

```
WITH data AS
  (SELECT array[1,2,3] as arr
   UNION ALL SELECT array[2,15,32] as arr
   UNION ALL SELECT array[5,16,14] as arr)
SELECT array_agg(arr[1]) from data;
```

The CTE is there just for input data, the actual meat is the `array_agg(arr[1])`. This will of course work for any number of input arrays.

Comment: The query applied to a set of rows gives an incorrect result.

Comment: The same query without the use of unnest returned an array like I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Given this table and values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE arrtbl (
   arrtbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , arr int[]
);

INSERT INTO arrtbl (arr) VALUES 
  ('{{1,2,3},{2,15,32},{5,16,14}}')
, ('{{17,22},{1,15},{16,14}}')   -- dimensions can vary across rows!
, ('{}')
, (null);
```

This would do the job for all rows:

```sql
SELECT arrtbl_id, array_agg(a) AS a1
FROM   arrtbl t
    ,  unnest(t.arr[:][1]) a
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Why `[:]`?

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1/44448230#44448230)

So only if there can be non-standard array-subscripts.

Result:

```
arrtbl_id | a1
----------+-----------
1         | '{1,2,5}'
2         | '{17,1,16}'
```

Rows with empty / NULL array in `arr` are dropped from the result.
Also, while the above usually works, rather use this **safe syntax**:

```sql
SELECT arrtbl_id, array_agg(a.a ORDER BY a.ordinality)
FROM   arrtbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.arr[:][1]) WITH ORDINALITY a ON true
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The same, more explicit, and a single sort in a subquery is typically faster:

```sql
SELECT arrtbl_id, array_agg(elem)
FROM  (
   SELECT t.arrtbl_id, a.elem
   FROM   arrtbl t
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.arr[:][1]) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, ord) ON true
   ORDER  BY t.arrtbl_id, a.ord
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
arrtbl_id | a1
----------+-----------
1         | '{1,2,5}'
2         | '{17,1,16}'
3         | null
4         | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=357a4dfa174bb50a323558f081787edb)*

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)