# How to sort two dimensional int array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, sorting

```
{{5,23}, {8,45}, {1,12}}
```

I want to sort this array according the first element of each sub-array elements, like;

```
{{1,12}, {5,23}, {8,45}}
```

How can I do that?

**Edit:**

This code works;

```
create or replace function arraysortingaccordingfirstindexofsubarrayelements()
returns void as $$
declare samplearraydata integer[][];
declare sortedarraydata int[][];
begin
samplearraydata:=ARRAY[[5,8], [1,6],[3,9]];
EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE temptable (
   firstindex integer,
   secondindex integer
) on commit drop;';
WITH
    data as (select samplearraydata as arr) 
insert into temptable select   
    arr[i][1], 
    arr[i][2] FROM data, 
    generate_subscripts((SELECT arr FROM data), 1) i 
    order by 1;
sortedarraydata:=(SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[y.firstindex, y.secondindex]])) FROM   temptable y;
raise notice '%', sortedarraydata;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE arrtbl (
   firstindex integer,
   secondindex integer
) on commit drop;
```

Credits to Erwin:)

Comment: As *always*, please your version of Postgres. And are you taking values from table rows or just dealing with a single value?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter 9.4 i am taking values from table rows...i am gonna sort the values of array that is being in every row and then update it in sorted way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Postgres 9.5 or newer

ships with a variant of `array_agg()` that serves as drop-in replacement for the custom aggregate function `array_agg_mult()` below - and is considerably faster. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)

> ```
> Function                Argument Type(s)   Return Type
> array_agg(expression)   any array type     same as argument data type  
>
> Description
> input arrays concatenated into array of one higher dimension
> (inputs must all have same dimensionality, and cannot be empty or NULL)
> ```

### Postgres 9.4 or older

#### Aggregate function

The built-in aggregate function `array_agg()` currently (Postgres 9.4) only works for non-array input data types. Since we are going to aggregate *arrays*, we need a custom aggregate function like detailed in this related answer:

- [Selecting data into a Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762398/selecting-data-into-a-postgres-array/11763245#11763245)

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray) (
   SFUNC     = array_cat
 , STYPE     = anyarray
 , INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

#### Accessing array

Basic understanding of array syntax / how to access arrays is required. Read [this chapter of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) if you aren't there, yet.

### Query

Then, based on the same setup as this earlier answer today (you may want to read that one, too):

- [Select every first element of array of integer arrays to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811591/select-every-first-element-of-array-of-integer-arrays-to-array/30846572#30846572)

```
SELECT arrtbl_id
     , array_agg_mult(arr[i:i][lo2:up2] ORDER BY arr[i:i][lo2])
FROM  (SELECT arrtbl_id, arr
            , array_lower(arr, 2) AS lo2
            , array_upper(arr, 2) AS up2
       FROM   arrtbl) t
     , generate_subscripts(t.arr, 1) i
GROUP  BY 1;
```

#### Explanation

1. Compute lower and upper bound for the 2nd array dimension in the base table, that's cheaper than repeating it for every array slice.

   I am not simply starting with index 1 to cover a possible corner case. Postgres allows non-standard array subscripts:

   - [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1)
2. `LATERAL` join the base table to `generate_subscripts(arr,1)` to get the first index for each sub-array (no matter how many dimensions).
3. The expression `arr[i:i][lo2:up2]` (or simply `arr[i:i][:]` in pg 9.6+) returns each array slice preserving dimensions. This **works for any number of elements and dimensions** (greater than 1).
4. The expression `arr[i:i][lo2]` returns the first slice within each array slice, which defines sort order. For strictly 2-dimnesional arrays, you can use `arr[i][lo2]` to return the first *element* of each slice as well, but the former works for *any* dimensionality greater than 1.
5. Aggregate with `array_agg_mult()` which happily accepts values of appropriate dimension (everything falls into place nicely).

Answer (score 0):

Since Postgres 9.4 if you can break your two dimensional array to two one dimensional arrays you can use operator

```
unnest(anyarray, anyarray [, ...])
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[6,4,3,5], ARRAY[64,2,1,-1], ARRAY[45,2,4,6]) ORDER BY 1
```

Return:

```
4   2   2
3   1   4
5   -1  6
6   64  45
```

If you want to sort by third elemen, you should change

```
... ORDER BY 3
```