# Removed the last element from a json[]?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a `json[]` array (_result_group) in PostgreSQL 9.4, and I want to remove its last json element (_current). I prepared with:

```
_result_group := (SELECT array_append(_result_group,_current));
```

And tried to remove with:

```
SELECT _result_group[1:array_length(_result_group,1) -1] INTO _result_group;
```

But it didn't work.
How to do this?

Comment: So this is plpgsql code. `_result_group` is defined as `json[]` and `_current` as `json`? Initialized how exactly? Can you provide a complete, failing plpgsql block? And what exactly happens when it *does not work*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the *last* element from *any* array (including `json[]`) with the means of Postgres 9.4, obviously within plpgsql code:

```
_result_group := _result_group[1:cardinality(_result_group)-1];
```

Assuming a 1-dimensional array with default subscripts starting with *1*.

You get an empty array for empty array input and null for null.

According to [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), `cardinality()` ...

> returns the total number of elements in the array, or 0 if the array is empty

Then just take the array slice from 1 to cardinality -1.

Then again, your attempt should work as well:

```
SELECT _result_group[1:array_length(_result_group,1) -1] INTO _result_group;
```

For non-standard array subscripts see:

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1/44448230)

Comment: Apparently the problem was a conditional, I finished using `SELECT _result_group[1:array_length(_result_group,1) -1] INTO _result_group;` and it worked