# Postgres FOR LOOP

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, for-loop, random, plpgsql

I am trying to get 25 random samples of 15,000 IDs from a table. Instead of manually pressing run every time, I'm trying to do a loop. Which I fully understand is not the optimum use of Postgres, but it is the tool I have. This is what I have so far:

```
for i in 1..25 LOOP
   insert into playtime.meta_random_sample
   select i, ID
   from   tbl
   order  by random() limit 15000
end loop
```

Answer (score 218):

[**Procedural** elements like **loops**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS) are not part of the SQL language and can only be used inside the body of a procedural language [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html), [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) (Postgres 11 or later) or a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement, where such additional elements are defined by the respective procedural language. The default is [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), but [there are others](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html).

Example with plpgsql:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..25 LOOP
      INSERT INTO playtime.meta_random_sample
         (col_i, col_id)                       -- declare target columns!
      SELECT  i,     id
      FROM   tbl
      ORDER  BY random()
      LIMIT  15000;
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

For many tasks that can be solved with a loop, there is a shorter and faster **set-based** solution around the corner. Pure SQL equivalent for your example:

```sql
INSERT INTO playtime.meta_random_sample (col_i, col_id)
SELECT t.*
FROM   generate_series(1,25) i
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT i, id
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY random()
   LIMIT  15000
   ) t;
```

About [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

About optimizing performance of random selections:

- [Best way to select random rows PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674718/best-way-to-select-random-rows-postgresql)

Comment: +1 I know this is almost 9 years old, but thanks so much for the set based example. I struggle with non trivial set based queries, and this example was exactly what i needed for my data generation task. Sql is pretty elegant.

Comment: What does the "BEGIN" and "END" wrapping the for loop do? Why is it needed?

Comment: @KyleMcClellan: That's not "for the loop", that's the syntax of any PL/pgSQL code block. [Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html)

Comment: Are those dollar signs optional? ($do$) If so, do they have any special meaning to you/are they ideomatic?

Comment: @Lauro235 See "dollar-quoting" https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860

Answer (score 11):

Below is example you can use:

```
create temp table test2 (
  id1  numeric,
  id2  numeric,
  id3  numeric,
  id4  numeric,
  id5  numeric,
  id6  numeric,
  id7  numeric,
  id8  numeric,
  id9  numeric,
  id10 numeric) 
with (oids = false);

do
$do$
declare
     i int;
begin
for  i in 1..100000
loop
    insert into test2  values (random(), i * random(), i / random(), i + random(), i * random(), i / random(), i + random(), i * random(), i / random(), i + random());
end loop;
end;
$do$;
```

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this question and, while it is old, I figured I'd add an answer for the archives. The OP asked about for loops, but their goal was to gather a random sample of rows from the table. For that task, Postgres 9.5+ offers the TABLESAMPLE clause on WHERE. Here's a good rundown:

https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/tablesample-in-postgresql-9-5-2/

I tend to use Bernoulli as it's row-based rather than page-based, but the original question is about a specific row count. For that, there's a built-in extension:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tsm-system-rows.html

```
CREATE EXTENSION tsm_system_rows;
```

Then you can grab whatever number of rows you want:

```
select * from playtime tablesample system_rows (15);
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it more convenient to make a connection using a procedural programming language (like Python) and do these types of queries.

```py
import psycopg2
connection_psql = psycopg2.connect( user="admin_user"
                                  , password="***"
                                  , port="5432"
                                  , database="myDB"
                                  , host="[ENDPOINT]")
cursor_psql = connection_psql.cursor()

myList = [...]
for item in myList:
  cursor_psql.execute('''
    -- The query goes here
  ''')

connection_psql.commit()
cursor_psql.close()
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but then it can become a problem when the number of calls to the db you need to make are large.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one complex postgres function involving UUID **Array**, **For loop**, **Case** condition and **Enum** data update. This function parses each row and checks for the condition and updates the individual row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION order_status_update() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  oid_list uuid[];
  oid uuid;
BEGIN
  SELECT array_agg(order_id) FROM order INTO oid_list;
  FOREACH uid IN ARRAY uid_list
  LOOP
    WITH status_cmp AS (select COUNT(sku)=0 AS empty, 
                    COUNT(sku)<COUNT(sku_order_id) AS partial, 
                    COUNT(sku)=COUNT(sku_order_id) AS full 
                    FROM fulfillment 
                    WHERE order_id=oid)
    UPDATE order
    SET status=CASE WHEN status_cmp.empty THEN 'EMPTY'::orderstatus
    WHEN status_cmp.full THEN 'FULL'::orderstatus
    WHEN status_cmp.partial THEN 'PARTIAL'::orderstatus
    ELSE null
    END 
    FROM status_cmp
    WHERE order_id=uid;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To run the above function

```
SELECT order_status_update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using procedure.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE pg_temp_3.insert_data()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO meta_random_sample(col_serial, parent_id)
SELECT t.*
FROM   generate_series(1,25) i
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT i, parent_id
   FROM    parent_tree order by random() limit 2
   ) t;
END;
```

Call the procedure.

```
call pg_temp_3.insert_data();
```

PostgreSQL manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html