# Syntax error in a Postgres statement with procedural code

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql, generate-series

I was trying to make a basic for loop sample. Couldn't find what I did wrong. Can you please help:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i_ IN 1..100 LOOP
        INSERT INTO "MYSHM".aaa values (i_,i_ + 1 ,i_ + 2,i_ + 3);
    END LOOP;
END
```

> [ERROR    ] 2.0-2: syntax error, unexpected character

Comment: [Similar question today.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procedural code is only allowed inside a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement or a [function body](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).
Using the default procedural language [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) (but there are [many other options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xplang.html)):

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..100 LOOP
      INSERT INTO "MYSHM".aaa   -- column definition list ?!
      VALUES (i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3);
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Or, better, recast your problem as set-based operation with [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html):

```
INSERT INTO "MYSHM".aaa         -- column definition list ?!
SELECT i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3
FROM   generate_series(1,100) i;
```