# How to run for loop in PostgreSQL over answers of function results or select query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, nested

I was looking for a way to do nested iteration over the PostgreSQL function results or select query that finally give me desired output

`for(answers of query 1)
{
      for(answer of query 2) 
       {
        select x from Table A where a='answer from query 1 & b>='answer of query 2(1)' & b<='answer from query 2(2)'
}
}`

My 'second for' loop returns 2 value using each and every result from my 'first for loop'.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop) post but its doesn't explains me nested for loop

Comment: Hard to give an answer if there is no real code visible, but *I* would say that you should write this as a single query with a join.

Comment: Second that, I realized its not a good practice to use loop in procedural language