# SQL: insert multiple rows at once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array of values like this (`restaurant_id` is not a primary key):

```
[
{restaurant_id:1, day_of_week:0, from_time: "12:00", to_time: "14:00", is_open:false },
{restaurant_id:1, day_of_week:1, from_time: "12:00", to_time: "14:00", is_open:true },
{restaurant_id:1, day_of_week:2, from_time: "12:00", to_time: "14:00", is_open:true },
...
]
```

One entry for every day.

I would like to save each of them as a new row in a `PostgreSQL` database.

I have this query for one insert:

```
INSERT INTO schedules (restaurant_id, day_of_week, from_time, to_time, is_open) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING schedules;
```

Should I do 7 `INSERT` statements or can I loop and save all in one statement?

What would be the query with the loop?

**EDIT:**

So I could do in one query something like this, as suggested:

```
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
        (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
        (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
        (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
        (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
        (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
        (?, ?, ?, ? ?)
```

but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: i assume you are using  some kind of programming lauguage also as you have mentioned  *"What would be the query with the loop?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those input values are actually part of a JSON array, you can use that directly:

```
INSERT INTO schedules (restaurant_id, day_of_week, from_time, to_time, is_open) 
select (v ->> 'restaurant_id')::int, 
       (v ->> 'day_of_week')::int,
       (v ->> 'from_time')::time,
       (v ->> 'to_time')::time,
       (v ->> 'is_open')::boolean
from jsonb_array_elements('
[
  {"restaurant_id":1, "day_of_week":0, "from_time": "12:00", "to_time": "14:00", "is_open":"false" },
  {"restaurant_id":1, "day_of_week":1, "from_time": "12:00", "to_time": "14:00", "is_open":"true" },
  {"restaurant_id":1, "day_of_week":2, "from_time": "12:00", "to_time": "14:00", "is_open":"true" }
]'::jsonb) as t(v);
```

Of course you need to replace the hardcoded string value with a proper parameter, e.g. `from jsonb_array_elements(cast(? as jsonb))`

Answer (score 4):

If all other values are constant(or derivable from the *running* variable), you can use `generate_series()`

---

```
INSERT INTO schedules (restaurant_id, day_of_week
           , from_time, to_time, is_open) 
SELECT 1, gs, '10:00','22:00', True
FROM generate_series(0,6) gs
        ;
```

---

Docs for `generate_series`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-srf.html

Comment: Is that a postgres specific function?

Comment: Yes. Generate_series() is a postgres extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can issue one insert.  I would recommend using parameters:

```
INSERT INTO schedules (restaurant_id, day_of_week, from_time, to_time, is_open)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
           (?, ?, ?, ? ?),
           . . .
    RETURNING *;
```

Comment: Ah yes! So better to explicitly setting VALUES for each row, than looping through the array?

Answer (score 2):

INSERT INTO USERS(id,name,age)
VALUES
(1, 'Talha', 22),
(2, 'John', 41),
(3, 'William', 32);

This will work i guess.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know if I could loop and avoid writing `(1, 'Talha', 22),` 7 times...

Comment: Kevin Amiranoff, 
You  can use stored procedures of mysql for that.

 begin
       for i in 1 .. 100000
       loop
           insert into users values ( i, 'Talha' ,20+i);
      end loop;
      commit;
 end;

Answer (score -1):

Kevin Amiranoff, 
You  can use stored procedures of mysql for that.

begin
       for i in 1 .. 100000
       loop
           insert into users values ( i, 'Talha' ,20+i);
      end loop;
      commit;
 end;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop

refer to this link , it might help