# Can PostgreSQL use FOR LOOP in ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, for-loop, sql-order-by

Can I make SQL statements like this?

```
    SELECT     
        ARRAY[array]
    FROM   table1
    ORDER BY 
       FOR i in array_length(array,1) LOOP 
                array[i]::numeric
            END LOOP;
```

The result I want is:

```
SELECT     
   ARRAY[array]
FROM   table1
ORDER BY array[1]::numeric, array[2]::numeric, ...
```

Can I? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no `LOOP` in SQL. It's an element of procedural languages like PL/pgSQL, though. See:

- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)

But there is a **simpler way**:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   table1
ORDER  BY array_column::numeric[];
```

Arrays values are sorted by element values left-to-right out of the box.

Requirements:

1. Column `array_column` must be an array with an element type that has a registered cast to `numeric`. Like `text` or `varchar` or some others.
   Else, you may be able to use `text[]` as stepping stone: `array_column::text[]:numeric[]`.
2. Each element can be projected to a legal `numeric` value.

Comment: Oh.. I'm sorry that I can't, but thank you. :)