# Best way to check for "empty or null value"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, null, coalesce

What is best way to check if value is null or empty string in Postgres sql statements?

Value can be long expression so it is preferable that it is written only once in check.

Currently I'm using:

```
coalesce( trim(stringexpression),'')=''
```

But it looks a bit ugly.

`stringexpression` may be `char(n)` column or expression containing `char(n)` columns with trailing spaces.

What is best way?

Comment: Using `char` is almost always the wrong choice due to padding (and the resulting space waste). But apart from that: I don't think there is a better solution.

Comment: Why ugly? Logical and legible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I think there is.

Answer (score 509, accepted):

The expression `stringexpression = ''` yields:

`true`   .. for `''` (or for *any* string consisting of only spaces with the data type `char(n)`)
`null`   .. for `null`
`false`  .. for anything else

#### *"`stringexpression` is either null or empty"*

To check for this, use:

```
(stringexpression = '') IS NOT FALSE
```

Or the reverse approach (may be easier to read):

```
(stringexpression <> '') IS NOT TRUE
```

Works for any [character type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) including `char(n)`.
[The manual about comparison operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)

**Or** use your original expression without [`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html), which would be costly noise for `char(n)` (see below), or incorrect for other character types: strings consisting of only spaces would pass as empty string.

```
coalesce(stringexpression, '') = ''
```

But the expressions at the top are faster.

#### *"`stringexpression` is neither null nor empty"*

Asserting the opposite is simpler:

```
stringexpression <> ''
```

Either way, document your exact intention in an added comment if there is room for ambiguity.

### About [`char(n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

The data type `char(n)` is short for `character(n)`.
`char` / `character` are short for `char(1)` / `character(1)`.
`bpchar` is an internal alias of `character`. (Think "**b**lank-**p**added **char**acter".)
This data type is supported for historical reasons and for compatibility with the SQL standard, but its use is [**discouraged in Postgres**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html):

> In most situations `text` or `character varying` should be used instead.

Do not confuse `char(n)` with other, useful, character types [`varchar(n)`, `varchar`, `text` or `"char"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) (with double-quotes).

In `char(n)` an *empty string* is not different from any other string consisting of only spaces. All of these are folded to *n* spaces in `char(n)` per definition of the type. It follows logically that the above expressions work for `char(n)` as well - just as much as these (which wouldn't work for other character types):

```
coalesce(stringexpression, '  ') = '  '
coalesce(stringexpression, '') = '       '
```

#### Demo

Empty string equals any string of spaces when cast to `char(n)`:

```
SELECT ''::char(5) = ''::char(5)     AS eq1
     , ''::char(5) = '  '::char(5)   AS eq2
     , ''::char(5) = '    '::char(5) AS eq3;
```

Result:

```
 eq1 | eq2 | eq3
 ----+-----+----
 t   | t   | t
```

Test for "null or empty string" with `char(n)`:

```sql
SELECT stringexpression 
     , stringexpression = ''                   AS base_test
     , (stringexpression = '')  IS NOT FALSE   AS test1
     , (stringexpression <> '') IS NOT TRUE    AS test2
     , coalesce(stringexpression, '') = ''     AS coalesce1
     , coalesce(stringexpression, '  ') = '  ' AS coalesce2
     , coalesce(stringexpression, '') = '  '   AS coalesce3
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('foo'::char(5))
   , ('')
   , ('   ')                -- not different from '' in char(n)
   , (null)
   ) sub(stringexpression);
```

Result:

```
 stringexpression | base_test | test1 | test2 | coalesce1 | coalesce2 | coalesce3 
------------------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 foo              | f         | f     | f     | f         | f         | f
                  | t         | t     | t     | t         | t         | t
                  | t         | t     | t     | t         | t         | t
 null             | null      | t     | t     | t         | t         | t
```

Test for "null or empty string" with `text`:

```
SELECT stringexpression 
     , stringexpression = ''                   AS base_test
     , (stringexpression = '')  IS NOT FALSE   AS test1
     , (stringexpression <> '') IS NOT TRUE    AS test2
     , coalesce(stringexpression, '') = ''     AS coalesce1
     , coalesce(stringexpression, '  ') = '  ' AS coalesce2
     , coalesce(stringexpression, '') = '  '   AS coalesce3
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('foo'::text)
   , ('')
   , ('   ')                -- different from '' in sane character types
   , (null)
   ) sub(stringexpression);
```

Result:

```
 stringexpression | base_test | test1 | test2 | coalesce1 | coalesce2 | coalesce3 
------------------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 foo              | f         | f     | f     | f         | f         | f
                  | t         | t     | t     | t         | f         | f
                  | f         | f     | f     | f         | f         | f
 null             | null      | t     | t     | t         | t         | f
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c1a384467b20eb691906c83a6c41a5bc)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2066)</sub>

Related:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it doesn't check for leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: OP asks for the `best way to check if value is null or empty string`. The `trim()` call is (comparatively) expensive - and just not necessary. I added more about `char(n)` and "empty string".

Comment: You wrote that any string expression containing only spaces is equal to `''` . Can I remove trim and use `coalesce(stringexpression,'')=''` to check. This looks more readable to me compared to your answer.

Comment: @Andrus: Yes, you can. I added that and some more to the answer.

Comment: `select coalesce(' ', '') = ''`  returns false. So TRIM() is required

Comment: But `coalesce(' '::char(5), '') = ''` does not. I would use one of the top two expressions in any case, which work for any character type and are fastest and cleanest.

Comment: The fastest queries you mention are not working on Oracle.                    
       This query will work on oracle and postgres :     WHERE NOT(stringexpression <> '');

Comment: @Woody: It will return NULL for NULL input. That's *not* what the question is asking for. This answer is for Postgres, not Oracle, where  NULL and the empty string are considered the same - in violation of the SQL standard.

Comment: You are right, coalesce will do the job for Oracle, thanks

Comment: The expression "Or the reverse approach (may be easier to read): (stringexpression <> '') IS NOT TRUE" is not true.

Comment: @ayhan: What's not true?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that line. By saying "reverse approach", I thought "stringexpression is neither NULL nor empty" is meant, but I see that another way of expressing "stringexpression is either NULL or empty" is shown at that line. So that expression is correct. Sorry.

Comment: Using `(stringexpression = '') IS NOT FALSE` is a bad advice because of poor readablity. It may be confusing for the reader as to what happens when stringexpression is NULL. Using coalesce fot this is a much better idea. Readability is **important**. If someone misunderstands your code it may result in a bug. A lot of code is read by multiple people, with varying experience, over multiple years.

Comment: Google brought me here even though I was looking for the opposite case: `Not null Nor empty`... I wonder if you can add it as an fyi to complete the very nice answer... *EDIT*: well, it should be `(stringexpression = '') IS FALSE` xD

Comment: @Enissay: Simply `stringexpression <> ''` for *"Not null Nor empty"*. That's already added in above.

Comment: Using "Postgres 11" and only original version  with "coalesce" and "trim" (from question) works for space-filled strings for me:        
`coalesce( trim(stringexpression),'')=''`

Answer (score 116):

To check for null and empty:

```
coalesce(string, '') = ''
```

To check for null, empty and spaces (trim the string)

```
coalesce(TRIM(string), '') = ''
```

Comment: btw, `coalesce(a, ...b)` returns the first non-null value (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-conditional.html)

Comment: This presumably performs a linear search and ignores the index, so you should filter based on indexed fields first.

Answer (score 37):

Checking for the length of the string also works and is compact:

```
where length(stringexpression) > 0;
```

Comment: Did you check this for the NULL case?

Comment: Yes, I did. It does not return empty nor null string fields.

Comment: If you just need to check only empty values, then try this -> `where length(stringexpression) = 0;`. This works for me.

Comment: I like this solution, just note that is some cases calculating exact length may be relatively expensive operation.

Comment: In postgres, `length(NULL) > 0` return `NULL`, not `False`.

Comment: I tested this in Postico's SQL Query interface, and it does not work for `NULL`s.

Answer (score 16):

A lot of the answers are the shortest way, not the necessarily the best way if the column has lots of nulls.  Breaking the checks up allows the optimizer to evaluate the check faster as it doesn't have to do work on the other condition.

```
(stringexpression IS NOT NULL AND trim(stringexpression) != '')
```

The string comparison doesn't need to be evaluated since the first condition is false.

Answer (score 12):

another way is

```
nullif(trim(stringExpression),'') is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

If there may be empty trailing spaces, probably there isn't better solution. `COALESCE` is just for problems like yours.

Answer (score 2):

Something that I saw people using is `stringexpression > ''`. This may be not the fastest one, but happens to be one of the shortest.

Tried it on MS SQL as well as on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

found this post looking for a solution to 'don't show me data that is '' (blank or single space char) or null'. in my case, we only want to show the user records with these values populated. i hope this response helps another looking for the same. the answers above didn't work in my case.

our app is running rails with postgres. looking at how rails builds the query for `.where.not(company_website: [nil, ''])` in our app, which works just fine, i can see the resulting sql statement in console.

`WHERE NOT ((contacts.company_website = '' OR contacts.company_website IS NULL))`

i added this bit and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I like answer by yglodt, but calculating exact length may be expensive for big sets and big strings, so I go with:

```
coalesce(trim('a') > '','f')
```

Answer (score 0):

My preffered way to compare nullable fields is:
NULLIF(nullablefield, :ParameterValue) IS NULL AND NULLIF(:ParameterValue, nullablefield) IS NULL . This is cumbersome but is of universal use while Coalesce is impossible in some cases.

The second and inverse use of NULLIF is because "NULLIF(nullablefield, :ParameterValue) IS NULL" will always return "true" if the first parameter is null.

Answer (score 0):

If database having large number of records then `null check` can take more time 
you can use null check in different ways like :
1) `where columnname is null`
2) `where not exists()`
3) `WHERE (case when columnname is null then true end)`