# How to select by null or zero length?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query:

```
select text_b, id from articles where title is not null;
```

But i want to show results where text_b is not null and length of text_b > 0.
How to do it?

Comment: Is `text_b != ''` sufficient?

Comment: `where length(text_b) > 0`? Null values have no length (in fact, their length is null), and would be automatically excluded anyways.

Comment: @PaulRichter: It is. But rather use the standard SQL `text_b <> ''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select text_b, id 
from articles 
where title is not null
  and length(text_b) > 0;
```

or

```
select text_b, id 
from articles 
where title is not null
  and text_b <> '';
```

or to properly handle `null` values in `text_b`

```
select text_b, id 
from articles 
where title is not null
  and text_b is distinct from '';
```

Comment: @Nips: `text_b <> ''` is *all* you need. Details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625).