# Check if data has a default length and it's numeric in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

In my table I have a column that is a code of 6 digits.

```
myCode CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY CHECK ( SUBSTRING ( myCode ,1 ,1) >='0' AND
SUBSTRING ( myCode ,1 ,1) <= '9' AND ...#for all positions
```

Is there another method faster then this one ?

Comment: What is your plan for the millionth record?

Comment: @DanBracuk no plan becouse they are Codes of municipalities, provinces and regions. They are neither 200000 so :), I want just an optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler:

```
mycode ~ '\d{6}'
```

[`\d` is the class shorthand for digits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE).
Do *not* escape `\` with another `\` unless you are running with the long outdated `standard_conforming_strings = off`. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

No parentheses needed.
And you don't even need `^` and `$` to anchor the expression to begin and end (even if that doesn't hurt) while using `char(6)`. A rare use case where the data type is not complete nonsense. See:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)
- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Shorter strings are blank-padded and don't pass the `CHECK` constraint.
Longer string don't pass the length specification of the type `char(6)`.
(But careful! An *explicit* cast like `'1234567'::char(6)` silently truncates.)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (mycode char(6) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (mycode ~ '\d{6}'));
```

I would still advise not to use the outdated type `char(6)`. Odd behavior in corner cases. Use `text` instead. Then you actually need `^` and `$` in the regexp expression:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (mycode text PRIMARY KEY CHECK (mycode ~ '^\d{6}$'));
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6edb01151224f934569f83630f3af2c0)*

---

You commented (really a new question):

> and what about that digits inside has to be distinct?

Enforcing unique digits in the string is not as simple. If you have the [additional module **intarray**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) installed, there is an elegant solution with `sort()` and `uniq()`:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl3 (
   mycode varchar(6) PRIMARY KEY
 , CONSTRAINT chk_6_distinct_digits
      CHECK (cardinality(uniq(sort(string_to_array(mycode, NULL)::int[]))) = 6)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using regex:

```
CREATE TABLE tabq(myCode CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (myCode ~'^([0-9]{6})$') );
```

If you just want to identify records which do *not* match this pattern, you could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabq
WHERE myCode !~ '^\\d{6}$';
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/OKFCC50792)**

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for extending :)

Comment: Nah, you've been on fire lately and you deserve the upvotes :P

Comment: @TripTherapy: That's not in your question. Ask new questions as question - or edit this one while you don't change it substantially. Comments are not the place.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Escaping \ in `'^\\d{6}$'` is typically incorrect. See my added answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I've made this mistake before; I'll try to remember that for next time.