# Get all rows if keyword is null else return matching

Tags: node.js, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have a plpgsql function in Postgres. It's working fine when keyword is not null and returning the matching results but when keyword is null I want to ignore it and return arbitrary rows.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_companies(_keyword varchar(255))
RETURNS TABLE(
id INTEGER,
name VARCHAR,
isactive boolean
) AS $$

BEGIN
RETURN Query 
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.isactive FROM companydetail AS c
WHERE c.name ~* _keyword LIMIT 50 ;
END;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: yes. I meant if keyword is empty then return records without matching with empty keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify if it's NULL or it's empty:

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.isactive 
FROM companydetail AS c 
WHERE _keyword IS NULL
   OR _keyword = ''::varchar(255) 
   OR c.name ~* _keyword 
LIMIT 50 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

[@jahuuar provided a simple and elegant solution with a single `SELECT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49753274/939860) to solve this with a single query (also skipping empty strings if you need that). You don't need plpgsql or even a function for this.

While working with plpgsql, you can optimize performance:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_companies(_keyword varchar(255))
  RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR, isactive boolean) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _keyword <> '' THEN  -- exclude null and empty string
      RETURN QUERY 
      SELECT c.id, c.name, c.isactive
      FROM   companydetail AS c
      WHERE  c.name ~* _keyword
      LIMIT  50;
   ELSE
      RETURN QUERY 
      SELECT c.id, c.name, c.isactive
      FROM   companydetail AS c
      LIMIT  50;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Postgres can use separate, optimized plans for the two distinct queries this way. A trigram GIN index scan for the first query (you need the matching index, of course - see links below), a sequential scan for the second. And PL/pgSQL saves query plans when executed repeatedly in the same session.

Related:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)
- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)
- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)