# How to check 'any or limited' in the WHERE clause of a query?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_example(
    IN  check_ids      INT [],
    OUT recs           REFCURSOR,
    OUT po_result_code TEXT
) RETURNS RECORD LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN recs FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table t
      JOIN my_another_table tt on tt.tid = t.id
    WHERE t.enabled = TRUE
          AND tt.some = 1
          AND (
              check_ids IS NULL OR check_ids.count = 0 /* <-- problem here */
              OR t.id = ANY (check_ids)
          );

    po_result_code := 0;
    RETURN;
END;
$$;
```

Calling it results in the error message:

> ```
> Error: [42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "check_ids"  
> SQL state: 42P01
> ```

How to check 'argument is null or value in argument'?

Some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id      INT,
    enabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
);
CREATE TABLE my_another_table (
    tid    INT,
    "some" INT DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT t_another_to_my_fk FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES my_table (id)
);
INSERT INTO my_table (id, enabled) VALUES (1, TRUE);
INSERT INTO my_another_table (tid, "some") VALUES (1, 1);
```

Comment: Try replacing `check_ids.count` with `array_length(check_ids, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! @stickybit make answer please

Comment: You might clarify the title some more. And remember to always disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `check_ids.count` with `array_length(check_ids, 1)`.

Comment: or `cardinality(check_ids)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Why even call a function? Just `check_ids = '{}'`.

Answer (score 2):

To also ***let NULL and empty array pass***, replace:

```
(t.id = ANY (check_ids) OR check_ids IS NULL OR check_ids.count = 0)  -- illegal syntax
```

with the single expression:

```
(t.id = ANY (check_ids) OR (check_ids = '{}') IS NOT FALSE)
```

This would work, too, but a bit slower:

```
(t.id = ANY (check_ids) OR check_ids IS NULL OR check_ids = '{}')
```

Closely related answer for string types with detailed explanation:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

However, your actual question asks for something ***different***:

> How to check 'argument is null or value in argument'?

That would burn down to simply:

```
(t.id = ANY (check_ids) OR check_ids IS NULL)
```

All of this is in the realm of SQL and unrelated to PL/pgSQL.