# Cast to int instead of decimal?

Tags: postgresql, types, null, string-parsing, coalesce

I have field that has up to 9 comma separated values each of which have a string value and a numeric value separated by colon.  After parsing them all some of the values between 0 and 1 are being set to an integer rather than a numeric as cast.  The problem is obviously related to data type but I am unsure what is causing it or how to fix it. The problem only exists in the case statement, the split_part function seems to be working perfect.

Things I have tried:

1. `nvl(split_part(one,':',2),0)` =  COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matched
2. `nvl(split_part(one,':',2)::numeric,0)` => Invalid input syntax for type numeric
3. numerous other cast/convert variations
4. `(CASE WHEN split_part(one,':',2) = '' THEN 0::numeric ELSE split_part(one,':',2)::numeric END)::numeric` => runs but get int value of 0

When using the split_part function outside of case statement it does work correctly. However, I need the result to be zero for null values.

`split_part(one,':',2)` => 0.02068278096187390979 (expected result)

When running the code above I get zero but expect 0.02068278096187390979

Field "one" has the following value 'xyz: 0.02068278096187390979' before the split_part function.

EXAMPLE:

```
create table test(one varchar); 

insert into test values('XYZ: 0.50000000000000000000') 

select
  one ,split_part(one,':',2) as correct_value_for_those_that_are_not_null ,
  case 
    when split_part(one,':',2) = '' then null 
    else split_part(one,':',2)::numeric 
  end::numeric as this_one_is_the_problem
from test
```

Comment: I ran your code and got the correct numeric value...  the only issue I might see is the potential loss of precision.  I got "0.5" but not "0" for the "this one is the problem"

Comment: Got it, I changed to decimal instead of numeric.  Thanks much.

Comment: `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent in Postgres. Start your questions by disclosing the Postgres version in use, may be relevant. `nvl` is not a Postgres function.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I need the result to be zero for null values.

Your example does not deal with `null` values, though. Only `''`. Anyway, to replace **either** with `0` and no casting issues:

```sql
SELECT part1
    , CASE WHEN part2 <> '' THEN part2::numeric ELSE numeric '0' END AS part2
FROM  (
   SELECT split_part(one, ':', 1) AS part1
        , split_part(one, ':', 2) AS part2
   FROM   test
   ) sub;
```

See:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

Note that all SQL `CASE` branches *must* agree on a common data type. There have been minor adjustments in the logic that determines the result type in the past, so the version of Postgres may play a role in corner cases.

`nvl()`is not a Postgres function. You probably meant [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). The manual:

> This SQL-standard function provides capabilities similar to `NVL` and `IFNULL`, which are used in some other database systems.