# SQL: "condition is not true" pattern as replacement for "is null or not (condition)"

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, comparison

In SQL (specifically Postgres):

The clause `where not foo='bar'` in case `foo` is null evaluates into some sort of `null`, causing the row is not included in the result.

On the other hand, the clause `where (foo='bar') is not true` where `foo` is null evaluates into `true` (the row is included in the result).

So is the use of `(foo='bar') is not true` equivalent to `foo is null or not foo='bar'`?

It doesn't seem that people are using this pattern for some reason, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

> So is the use of `(foo='bar') is not true` equivalent to `foo is null or not foo='bar'`?

Yes. Or simpler:

```
foo IS NULL OR foo <> 'bar'
```

Or simpler, yet:

```
foo IS DISTINCT FROM 'bar'
```

Use the latter.
Details in the manual chapter [***Comparison Functions and Operators***.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)
Related:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)

Comment: As a side note, `is distinct from` can not use an index. However, `foo IS NULL OR foo <> 'bar'`might use an index (if suitable)

Comment: As a side note to the side note: A condition like `foo IS DISTINCT FROM 'bar'` rarely would use an index even if that's technically possible, as it typically qualifies for most rows, and that's where indexes typically don't help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
where coalesce(foo, 'foo') <> 'bar'
```

or

```
where not coalesce(foo, 'foo') = 'bar'
```

I suspect people are avoiding `IS NOT TRUE` because it doesn't work in Oracle and MS SQL Server.  The same reason people using MS SQL Server will avoid using the `ISNULL` function.

**Response to comment:**

I don't know what you mean by an impossible 'foo'.  Do you mean a value that's not possible?  Not true.  It just needs to not be 'bar'.
This still works:

```
declare @foo varchar(15)
declare @bar varchar(15)
set @bar = 'bar'
--set @foo = 'bar'
--set @foo = 'asdf'

select 7

where coalesce( @foo, 'not' + @bar) <> @bar
```

Comment: True, but when 'bar' is replaced by a parameter (the typical use case), you need an "impossible" 'foo'.