# How to allow multiple blanks (empty strings) using a unique index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a unique index like so in my migration

```
add_index :table, :name, unique: true
```

Now the unique constraint allows for multiple `nil` values however I also want blank values (empty strings `""`) to bypass unique constraint as well. What is the best way to keep the unique index but also bypass and allow multiple blank strings?

Answer (score 2):

Ref [indexes-partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) and [null_or_empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/297087)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name_constraint 
ON table (name) 
WHERE ((name <> '') IS NOT TRUE);
```

Ref [this](https://nts.strzibny.name/conditional-unique-indexes-in-rails-and-postgresql/) for how to write it in the rails migration.

```
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name_constraint ON table (name) WHERE ((name <> '') IS NOT TRUE);
SQL
```

Answer (score 2):

@Salil's answer did not work for me. It all looked good in the schema etc but I still got the non unique psql error when trying to save a second record with blank value.

This works for me in a Rails 6 migration (user and username case where a preexisting unique index was already there)

```
class ChangeUniqueConstraintOnUsername < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    remove_index :users, :username, name: :index_users_on_username
    add_index :users, :username, unique: true, where: "username != '' AND username IS NOT NULL"
  end

  def down
    remove_index :users, :username, name: :index_users_on_username
    add_index :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```