# Check if value is not null and not empty in a select query

Tags: postgresql

I have created a function in Postgresql and specified the returned type as `TABLE (id uuid, data boolean)`.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT table.id, (table.data <> '') as data FROM table;
END
```

But it will return NULL for "data" when data is NULL in the table. I was expecting it to return FALSE.

Data column is storing a JSON and I am trying to check if the stored value is not null and not empty

How can I make this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is distinct from` to use a null-safe comparison:

```
SELECT table.id, table.data is distinct from '' as data 
FROM table;
```

Another option is to treat an empty string like null:

```
SELECT table.id, nullif(table.data, '') is not null as data 
FROM table;
```

Comment: I just thought that <> also checks for NULL after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value). Your second solution solved my problem. Thanks.