# Lower(null) comparison with string does not return row

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I have these two tables `school_classes` and `classes`.

```
school_classes
------------------------
id | class_id 
 1 |  2
 2 |  1

classes
------------------------
id | status    | name
 1 | null      | A
 2 | null      | B
 3 | Active    | C 
 4 | Cancelled | D
```

Here is the query I am trying,

```
select
    c.status, c.name
from
    school_classes sc
join classes c on
    sc.class_id = c.id and (LOWER(c.status) != 'cancelled')
where
 sc.id = 1
```

For above query it returns empty result. But my understanding that `lower(null)` will be `'null'` which is not equal to `'cancelled'` so it should return the row.

When I change the status from null to some other string then the row is returned.

Comment: `lower(null)` is `null`, and `null` is not equal to anything, or different to anything, even to other nulls. In short, unlike in programming languages, `null` is not a value. Therefore is not different from `'cancelled'` and the row should not be returned.

Comment: @TheImpaler What is the fix? How I make it to filter only `cancelled` status and return the row even if the status is null?

Comment: `LOWER(c.status) is distinct from 'cancelled'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name's solution is the canonical solution according to the SQL Standard, that few engines actually implement. PostgreSQL does; isn't PostgreSQL great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my understanding that `lower(null)` will be `'null'` ...

It will be `NULL`, not `'null'`. The missing quotes matter, signifying it's not a string but a genuine `NULL` value - or `null`, capitalization does not matter.
There are various ways to fix, [IS NOT TRUE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) being possibly simplest:

```
AND (lower(c.status) = 'cancelled') IS NOT TRUE
```

Additional parentheses are optional since [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) works in our favor anyway.

See:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the nulls, you can check for them, as in:

```
select
    c.status, c.name
from
    school_classes sc
join classes c on
    sc.class_id = c.id
 and (LOWER(c.status) != 'cancelled' or c.status is null) 
where
 sc.id = 1
```