# Case in SQL returning two values instead of one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to return one value for two conditions in SQL `CASE` statement

```sql
CASE  
WHEN Col1 = 'false' OR Col1 IS NULL  THEN 'NA' 
ELSE ...
END
```

Data

```
Col1
-----
false
poor
moderate
null
```

In the query result, I'm getting two times "NA" repeatedly.
I'm expecting a one-time "NA"

**Output**

```
Col1
-----
NA
poor
moderate
NA
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Col1
-----
NA
poor
moderate
```

Comment: Can you share some of your data you are working with and the expected output

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Col1 can contain data like 
'false', null, 'poor' etc

Comment: *I'm getting two times "NA" repeatedly.* Provide complete code. CASE operator **cannot** produce "doubled" output even in theory..

Comment: Use DISTINCT to return unique records.

Comment: Why is there 1 less row in your expected result than in your source data? DO you just want one NA even if there are many which meet the condition for setting NA?

Answer (score 0):

UNION where first select picks NA and second select picks the others

```
select 'NA' as col1 from t where col1 is null or col1 ='false'
union 
select col1 from t where col1 is not null and col1 <> 'false'
```

UNION comes with and implied distinct so the outcome is

```
+----------+
| col1     |
+----------+
| NA       |
| poor     |
| moderate |
+----------+
3 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want `DISTINCT` results?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN col1 <> 'false' THEN col1 ELSE 'NA' END AS col1
FROM   tbl;
```

With a simplified `CASE` expression, too. See:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766084/best-way-to-check-for-empty-or-null-value/23767625#23767625)