# PL/pgSQL function seems be be choosing the wrong variable?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, error-handling, plpgsql

I'm trying to make this work and I tested it without the two artikli_racun updates and it worked. So if I have only the cena(price) it will work and it will take $2, but clearly here it says that the row "artikel" doesn't exist and I have no idea what to do. It takes $1 and I need a solution to why it takes this variable...

```
NAPAKA:  stolpec "artikel" ne obstaja

KONTEKST:  SQL statement "UPDATE artikli_racun SET id_artikla=(SELECT id FROM artikli WHERE ime=$1 ) WHERE artikel= $1 "
PL/pgSQL function "racun123" line 6 at SQL statement


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION racun123(integer,varchar) RETURNS 
BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT zaloga FROM artikli WHERE ime=$2)>0 THEN
INSERT INTO racun1(id,artikel) VALUES($1,$2);
UPDATE racun1 SET cena=(SELECT prodajna_cena FROM artikli WHERE 
ime=$2) WHERE artikel=$2;
UPDATE artikli_racun SET id_artikla=(SELECT id FROM artikli WHERE 
ime=$2) WHERE artikel=$2;
UPDATE artikli_racun SET id_racuna=(SELECT id FROM racun1 WHERE 
ime=$2) WHERE artikel=$2;
UPDATE artikli set zaloga=zaloga-1 WHERE ime=$2;
RETURN true;
ELSE RETURN false;
END IF;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: To get English error messages run `SET lc_messages = 'C'` in your session. To fix your code properly, we would need to see table definitions, mot importantly (but not limited to) `\d artikli_racun` in `psql`.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message table `artikli_racun` is missing column `artikel`.
By the way, there are multiple update statements operating on the same tables - they can be merged into one.

Comment: That is not the problem. My problem is this sentence KONTEKST:  SQL statement "UPDATE artikli_racun SET id_artikla=(SELECT id FROM artikli WHERE ime=$1 ) WHERE artikel= $1 " Where it shows that it matched with the first variable, where it should have matched with the $2 variable

Comment: @someone123 - no, it's not. Each statement is its own prepared query, so the $1 is as viewed from "inside" the query. Try giving your function parameters names and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The ordinal parameter **`$1`** in the error message is **completely unrelated** to ordinal parameters `$1` and `$2` in the function body. Just the same notation.

If you replace `$1` and `$2` with [**named parameters**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) in your function, you will still see `$1` and `$2` in the error message, which are used in the context of a prepared statement. PL/pgSQL executes each statement as prepared statement internally and caches query plans.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION racun123(_param1 integer, _param2 varchar)
  RETURNS ...

...

UPDATE artikli_racun
SET id_artikla = (SELECT id FROM artikli WHERE ime = _param2)
WHERE artikel = _param2;
 
...
```

The error message will still say:

```
SQL statement "UPDATE artikli_racun
 SET id_artikla=(SELECT id FROM artikli WHERE ime=$1 ) WHERE artikel= $1
```

Aside: your function could be improved, but the best solution depends on undisclosed details.